# HTML and Python?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I have a website design that I can turn into HTML that needs Python integration. Everything in the design is static except one part that has a table of values that needs to be updated every 15 minutes. I have my Python code ready to do this, but I have no idea how to combine Python and HTML.

My website will function just like this one: http://170.94.200.136/weather/Inversion.aspx, including the same table.

Comment: look at the Django framework.

Comment: HTML is front-end, Python is back-end, so you can't 'combine HTML & Python', you can make Python process some HTML and then send it to the user.

Comment: well you can put Django on the backend (thats python too), and then hook up javascript in your html to interface with the backend .

Comment: If you don't want to learn Django, you could modify your Python script to create a complete web page instead of just the values table, and then set up a cron job to call that python script every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html

I found it useful.

Or you can start using Flask for your task. [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)